# Column flow in Bootstrap

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a form more responsive to handle smaller browsers. Currently, we're using bootstrap to help with the layout but I am not adverse to other alternative solutions. In this particular view, we have two columns each with varying amounts of data. The trick is the group in the upper right needs to stay at the top of the page regardless of whether we are rendering this in one column or two. The groups below the upper right section should flow below any groups from the left hand column. Here's an illustration of what we are trying to achieve:

2-column:

```
 L1   R1
 L2   R2
 L3
```

1 column:

```
R1
L1
L2
L3
R2
```

Using Bootstrap, I'm able to get the R1 to stay at the top using col-pull/col-push, but the right hand column values under R1 flow after all values from the left hand column have rendered thus resulting in:

```
 L1   R1
 L2   
 L3
      R2
```

Here's the markup that I've attempted so far. I've also posted a jsfiddle for those who need a live sample to play with at http://jsfiddle.net/jimwooley/g8r35/.

```
<div class="row row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5 col-xs-12">R1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-7 col-xs-12">L1<br />
         L2<br />
         L3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-5 col-xs-12">R2<br />
         R3</div>
</div>
```

Note: the hights of the sections varies, so I can't just flow line two right below or beside line two left because they may fall half-way between the two. Also, I can't use columns here because the result needs to work with IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Make them column 6 instead of 12? Since bootstrap looks for 12 on a page? Therefore a call of 6 or 3 should show single column. (tablet or mobile in this example). where full screen would show 2 columns.

I could be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I'm setting them to 12 if xs which does push them to one column. With the push/pull the cells are ordering as expected in one column. The problem is getting the display to appear correctly for the two column version.

Answer (score 0):

While I admit the duplication is not a good thing, I've had success in using the hidden-* and visible-* classes from Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5 col-xs-12">
        <div>
            Upper Right<br />
            line 1<br />
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-xs" >Below Right<br />
            line 1<br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-7 col-xs-12">Upper Left<br />
        line 1<br />
        line 1<br />
        line 1<br />
        line 1<br />
        line 1<br />
    </div>
    <div class="visible-xs">
        Below Right<br />
        line 1<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/darronj/t8nYn/

Comment: I'll keep that option in mind. Naturally I simplified the question as compared to the actual task I'm trying to accomplish. In reality each section may have hundreds of dom elements bound to properties through angular, so the duplication will drastically reduce client performance in this case when targeting IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have R1 just push-right and allow the columns to wrap around it? That way it will always be on top. It would need to be first.

Comment: Can you get that to work in the jsfiddle? I've tried the options I can think of regarding float and cm-push, but haven't been able to get it to work so far.